# Using Git with Folder Version History

Tags: git, version-control

I am currently using Git (and a novice there), but a colleague without any technical knowledge wants to use a folder structure, where a version is saved into an enumerated folder structure (i.e. folders 1.1, 1.2, etc.)

Is there a way to make these workflows compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get the oldest folder, commit it's content into (new) repository
- Get every next version, sync content of *your* Working Directory for repo with this (every next) folder's content, commit synced as new changeset
- Repeat the above point on appearing new version of work